# Counting the equal-differences of an permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

I'm interesting in calculating how many permutations of $[n]$ have a consecutive difference (in absolute value) equal. For instance if $n=6$ the permutation $613425$ have common difference $2$ because $|1-3|=|4-2|$ are both equal to $2$ while the permutation $162534$ does not possess them.

I tried counting for some particular cases when all the differences are different and I got that:

If $n=3$, then there are $4$. 
If $n=4$, then there are $4$. 
If $n=5$, then there are $8$.

How could I try to solve the count? Thanks for the suggestions.

P.S.: Sorry for my English, I'm not native. :v

Comment: Is the problem from a book?

Comment: @quasi No, it's just a problem that I got from another

Comment: From another student?

Comment: From another exercise. Counting the fixed points in a permutation came up this problem. They are not related but it was interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to these problems, when you don't see an immediate approach to analyzing a count, is to get data, and look for a pattern.

Let $f(n)$ be the number of permutations of $[n]$ such that no two of the $n-1$ absolute differences of consecutive terms are equal.

You computed $f(n)$ for $n=3,4,5$, and you found
$$f(3) = 4,\;\;f(4)=4,\;\;f(5)=8$$
But it's not enough data to get a sense of a possible form for $f$.

My intuition was that there is no closed form expression for $f$, but in any case, more data is needed, which calls for writing a program. To analyze obscure counts, programming skills are a valuable asset.

In my case, I used Maple, and found
$$
f(1)=1,\;\;
f(2)=2,\;\;
f(3)=4,\;\;
f(4)=4,\;\;
f(5)=8
$$
$$
f(6)=24,\;\;
f(7)=32,\;\;
f(8)=40,\;\;
f(9)=120,\;\;
f(10)=296
$$
While the data doesn't suggest a clear pattern, at least it's more data.

An **oeis** lookup with the sequence
$$1,\,2,\,4,\,4,\,8,\,24,\,32,\,40,\,120,\,296$$
is a natural next step, and bingo, we find

$\qquad$https://oeis.org/A006967

which names these permutations as "graceful permutations".

A Google search on "graceful permutations", yields the link

$\qquad$http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GracefulPermutation.html

From these links, it's not clear to me as to whether a closed form for $f(n)$ is known. But such a scenario is not uncommon. There are many combinatorial counts which have a simple definition, but no known closed form.

Comment: This is a nice walkthrough, but is it what OP is counting? (it’s actually unclear to me what OP is counting, since apparently some adjacent entries don’t matter))

Comment: Adjacent entries _do_ matter. There are only $n-1$ consecutive pairs, and $n-1$ possible absolute differences. The problem, as stated, is to count the  number of permutations for which all $n-1$ absolute differences of consecutive terms are distinct. Or the complement, which is $n!$ minus that count.

Comment: I think I see: I initially assumed they wanted *all*consecutive differences equal, but now it seems like they just want at least (exactly?) two differences to be equal.

Comment: At least two.${}{}{}{}{}$